# After going through array values, repeat the process if there are more elements

Tags: javascript

So I have some elements that need to be filled with these months, dynamically. Right now, the process loops through once. Is there a way I can change it so it will continue to loop through that array until it runs out of ".point" elements in the html?

JS

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var monthsLength = months.length;
var points = $('.point');
for (var i = 0; i < monthsLength; i++) {
    var point = points[i];
    if (!point) {
        break;
    }
    point.setAttribute("data-date", months[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code syntax, I assume that you are using JQuery.

If the number of items is less or equals 12, then you may just ***shift*** element from the array of months for each ***point***.

```
$('.point').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-date", months.shift());  
});
```

If there are more than 12 points, then it would be better to get an appropriate month using the mod division operation for the index of the array. Using this way you may iterate over the months' array as much as it is necessary.

P.S.: You may inspect elements in the output window using the browser's dev tool to see results.

```js
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

$('.point').each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).attr("data-date", months[index % 12]);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='point'></div>
<div class='point'></div>
<div class='point'></div>
<div class='point'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer @zavg, but it still only loops through the array one time. If there are more than twelve ".point" elements, it stops. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the .filter() function would be better suited for this over .map(). You can specify your desired 'point' and it will only return items with it. You can then use that point data how you like.